# CakePHP 3 sessions table in database

Tags: session, cakephp, database-schema, cakephp-3.x

I have some questions regarding having CakePHP 3 `sessions` table stored in the database:

1) Is there a way to remname the table from `sessions` to a different name? If yes, where should I specify the new name?

2) Similarly to question 1: Is there a way to remname the names of colums in `sessions` table, so that CakePHP would still operate correctly?

3) Is there a simple way to add even the most basic encription of the `data` column of `sessions` table?

Comment: You need to get used to tagging your questions with the main [tag:cakephp] tag, additionally to the version specific ones, pretty much no one follows the [tag:cakephp-3.x] tag, hence you won't receive any (good) answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I will [cite the database session docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#database-sessions) and then also provide some answers. The answers in the docs are more complete.

1. Specify the model you want to use by including a 'model' key.

   ```
   'Session' => [
       'defaults' => 'database',
       'handler' => [
           'engine' => 'DatabaseSession',
           'model' => 'MyCustomSessions'
       ]
   ]
   ```
2. The DatabaseSession handler appears to hard code 'data' and some of the other columns. However, you can (and should) extend that class if you want to do something special
3. Based on what you want to do it appears creating your own SessionHandler is the way to go. It is quite simple to do and it is [outlined in the docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-handlers).

My best advice would to take a peek at cake's [DatabaseSession](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Network.Session.DatabaseSession.html). It seems that your requirements are special and it is probably your best course of action.